# Conditional joins with dynamic thresholds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing information about an event's date, and a configuration table, describing when to send reminders, and what the reminder contains. every event can have one or more reminders.

The configuration table contains:

- event type id (template_internal_id)
- reminder number
- reminder threshold (amount of days passed from event to send reminder by)
- reminder message

[configuration table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVDuR.png)

The second table contains a list of events, and should match reminder with the number of days passed since the event. Now, if I knew for a fact the number of possible thresholds, it would have looked something like this

```
select  template_internal_id,  create_date, 
DATEDIFF (DAY, msg_rfi.create_date, GETDATE()) as event_age
from events
left join configuration
on events.template_internal_id=configuration.template_internal_id
and event_age>first_threshold and event_age<second_threshold
```

and so forth to all thresholds. but, as I've mentioned, I don't know how many thresholds I will have. There can be 3 thresholds for one template and 5 thresholds for another. The query needs to operate a procedure that can handle both these cases (and others).

Would really appreciate your advises.

Thanks!

Comment: please add the events table structure and some sample data in it. it is  unclear what you mean by handle these cases. For example, say 2 days have passed and event.template_internal_id is 9001. what are you expecting to be returned in the query? what should the result be if the same query is run after 3 days have passed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the `remainder_num` (I'm guessing you're using it for running sequence) by getting the minimum id that hasn't passed the `deadline`.
After you have that `remainder_num`, your main query becomes simple:

```
SELECT e.template_internal_id, e.create_date,
  DATEDIFF(DAY, e.create_date, GETDATE()) AS event_age
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN configuration c
ON e.template_internal_id = c.template_internal_id
WHERE remainder_num = (
  SELECT MIN(remainder_num) FROM configuration c
  WHERE c.template_internal_id = e.template_internal_id
  AND c.deadline > DATEDIFF(DAY, e.create_date, GETDATE())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that the first 3 thresholds will always be used, so you can use those unconditionally.  For this example I'll be using `<` for all comparisons, but you'll need to adjust it for your needs.

```
ON ... AND event_age < first AND event_age < second AND event_age < third
```

At this point, the fourth and fifth thresholds are optional:

```
ON ... AND ... event_age < third AND (fourth IS NULL OR event_age < fourth) AND (fifth IS NULL OR event_age < fifth)
```

In this way, the thresholds are only used if they're populated.  If it's populated on all, then substitute `___ IS NULL` with `template_id <> ___`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. It's always going to be one threshold, and only that. The relevant threshold can be either one from the first to the 50th, but the range by which they're determined is dynamic.